# Get 404 error when POST data to a foreign key field with express and sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am following [This](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-express-and-postgres-using-sequelize) tutorial to learn express and sequelize with postgresql.

I have implemented a simple todo app server, I can successfully post a `Todo` item to the database, however when I try to follow their instructions and post a `TodoItem` to the database that is associated with the `Todo` item with a one to many relationship, I get this 404 error on postman.

I have checked that there is indeed a `Todo` with `id` of 2 in the database yet I cannot add a `TodoItem` that is associated with that `Todo`.

```
{
"name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
"parent": {
    "name": "error",
    "length": 128,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42703",
    "position": "76",
    "file": "parse_target.c",
    "line": "1034",
    "routine": "checkInsertTargets",
    "sql": "INSERT INTO \"TodoItems\" (\"id\",\"content\",\"complete\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\",\"todoId\") VALUES (DEFAULT,'abcd',false,'2020-06-12 21:37:23.063 +00:00','2020-06-12 21:37:23.063 +00:00','2') RETURNING *;"
},
"original": {
    "name": "error",
    "length": 128,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42703",
    "position": "76",
    "file": "parse_target.c",
    "line": "1034",
    "routine": "checkInsertTargets",
    "sql": "INSERT INTO \"TodoItems\" (\"id\",\"content\",\"complete\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\",\"todoId\") VALUES (DEFAULT,'abcd',false,'2020-06-12 21:37:23.063 +00:00','2020-06-12 21:37:23.063 +00:00','2') RETURNING *;"
},
"sql": "INSERT INTO \"TodoItems\" (\"id\",\"content\",\"complete\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\",\"todoId\") VALUES (DEFAULT,'abcd',false,'2020-06-12 21:37:23.063 +00:00','2020-06-12 21:37:23.063 +00:00','2') RETURNING *;"
  }
```

Here is how I set up my controllers:

```
const Todo = require('../models').Todo;

module.exports = {
create(req, res) {
    return Todo
        .create({
            title: req.body.title,
        })
        .then(todo => res.status(201).send(todo))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
},

list(req, res) {
    return Todo
        .findAll()
        .then(todos => res.status(200).send(todos))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
},
};
```

And here is how I set up the controller for TodoItem, as you can see I have console.log the request that is being sent and it is accurate with what is being sent.

```
const TodoItem = require('../models').TodoItem;

module.exports = {
create(req, res) {

  console.log(req.params.todoId);
  console.log(req.body.content);
  return TodoItem
      .create({
      content: req.body.content,
      todoId: req.params.todoId,
  })
      .then(todoItem => res.status(201).send(todoItem))
      .catch(error => res.status(404).send(error));
},};
```

And finally my models for TodoItem:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

const TodoItem = sequelize.define('TodoItem', {
  content: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
  },
  complete: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
  },
});

TodoItem.associate = (models) => {
  TodoItem.belongsTo(models.Todo, {
      foreignKey: 'todoId',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  });
};


return TodoItem;
};
```

And Model for Todo:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Todo = sequelize.define('Todo', {
  title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
  },
});

Todo.associate = (models) => {

  Todo.hasMany(models.TodoItem, {
      foreignKey: 'todoId',
      as: 'todoItems',
  });
};

return Todo;
};
```

As well as my routes:

```
const todosController = require('../controllers').todos;
const todoItemsController = require('../controllers').todoItems;

module.exports = (app) => {
app.get('/api', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome to the Todos API!',
}));

app.post('/api/todos', todosController.create);
app.get('/api/todos', todosController.list);
app.post('/api/todos/:todoId/items', todoItemsController.create);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out after googling a bit that the tutorial is outdated, and the association should be `foreignKey: 'todo_id'` instead of `foreignKey: 'todoId'`.